# how to reproduce a sound effect while loading a scene

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scene

how to reproduce a sound effect while loading a scene?
I would like to play a sound effect when moving to the next scene, but it does not play. I already tried with method DontDestroyOnLoad but it doesn't work and I get this error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LevelLoader.LoadNextLevel ()
this is my script to manage sounds:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoundManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AudioClip clikSound, shootSound;
    static AudioSource audioScr;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        clikSound = Resources.Load<AudioClip> ("clik");
        shootSound = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("shoot");
        audioScr = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public static void PlaySound(string clip)
    {
        switch (clip)
        {
            case "clik":
                audioScr.PlayOneShot(clikSound);
                    break;

            case "shoot":
                audioScr.PlayOneShot(shootSound);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the script for switching between scenes:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator transition;

    public float transitionTime = 1f;

    
    static AudioSource audioScr;
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(audioScr.gameObject);
        SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("shoot");
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
        
        

    }
    
    
    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int LevelIndex)
    {


        
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelIndex);
        
        
        
        

    }
   


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Becasuse you're required gameobjects are destroyed. AudioSource by itself not enough. Maybe your AudioListener destroyed?

To arrange those things. I recommend you to have multiple scenes. in example, Persistent scene, MenuScene, Level1 etc, and you can put your audios in Persistent scene.

You can have more than one scene via `SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);`. That's where multiple scenes gets it's power.

It may be hard but i recommend you to use [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.20/manual/index.html) for handling scenes and assets like audios.